# How to Split a 2D Gaussian pdf into a Grid of Equally Sized Volumes

Tags: integration, approximation, systems-of-equations

Let $f(x,y)$ be a Gaussian pdf for some known mean and covariance.

Given $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_N, y_M)$ such that
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_N} \int_{y_0}^{y_M} f(x,y) dy dx \approx 1$$

I would like to split the intervals $[x_0, x_N]$ and $[y_0, y_M]$ into $N+1$ and $M+1$ respectively (i.e. $\{x_0, x_1, \dots x_N\}, \{y_0, y_1, \dots y_M\}$) such that
$$\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \int_{y_{j}}^{y_{j+1}} f(x,y) dy dx \approx \frac{1}{NM}$$

**Work So Far**
My initial approach was to assume we had $N,M$ large enough to use the approximation

$$\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \int_{y_{j}}^{y_{j+1}} f(x,y) dy dx \approx f(x_i,y_j)(x_{i+1}-x_i)(y_{j+1}-y_j)$$

We then want to solve the system of equations
$$f(x_i,y_j)(x_{i+1}-x_i)(y_{j+1}-y_j) = \frac{1}{NM}$$

This gives $N+M-4$ unknowns and $NM$ equations. I was thinking of some sort of iterative method to solve this but was not sure of the best way to formulate it. Note that in the 1D case we can just substitute in our $x_0$ value and loop over all $i$. How best to proceed?

Comment: If the covariance matrix is diagonal then $x$ and $y$ are independent, so you just have to solve two one-dimensional problems. And that you can do by considering the cdf and dividing the vertical range $[0,1]$ into equal intervals.

Comment: Yes that is true I will edit to take that out as I wanted to consider the general case.

Comment: You're aware that if the covariance matrix is far from diagonal, you will not be able to get anywhere near equal probabilities in each cell?

Comment: Ah yes, that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the center and divide each semi interval in $N/2$ (with $N$ even).

so $x_0 = \mu_x$ and the interval go from $x_{-N/2}...x_0...x_{N/2}$

You can then use the inverse error function to compute each $x_i$ such that

$$\frac{1}N=\frac{1}{2}\left(erf\left(\frac{x_{i+1}-\mu_x}{\sqrt{2\sigma_x^2}}\right)-erf\left(\frac{x_{i}-\mu_x}{\sqrt{2\sigma_x^2}}\right)\right)$$

similarly over the y axis.

Comment: This leads to a system of equations similar to what I mentioned except I approximated the cdf.